# How do I translate "eternity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

For example, in *Those that disobeyed were frozen in place for all of eternity.* how should I translate *eternity*? Specifically, how do I translate it in the context of *a small eternity*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just *eterno*.

> *Tiuj, kiuj malobeis, estis fiksitaj surloke por ĉiam. / por tuta eterno.*

"In place" is *surloke* or *enloke*. If "frozen" is literal, then use *frostigitaj*.

I suppose "a small eternity" would be an *eterneto*, but that sounds a little too much like *Eterreto* ("Ethernet"). Maybe an *eta eterno*?

Comment: _Small eternity_ is a contradiction; it would be like saying _a small infinite_. There isn't a bigger eternity, or a bigger infinite.

Comment: There actually are bigger infinites than others (at least more densely populated than others). Take the set of all real numbers. Then, the set of all integers. They're both infinite, but technically all integers are just a piece of a bigger infinite, real numbers. More on topic, I like *eta eterno*.

Comment: Yes but, in my opinion, you have to be a math geek to know that

Answer (score 0):

I would say "eterneco" - "eterna" (eternal) + "-eco" (state, quality).

I'm not sure what "a small eternity" is even in English, so I'm not sure how to translate that one.